# Unable to fail C# test using assert.fail method

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am creating a test in codedUI, VS2013. I am using `assert.fail(failuredescripion)` inside my exception class. But I am getting the below mentioned error:

```
An exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.AssertFailedException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Assert.Fail failed.
```

Can anyone please suggest how to achieve this?
I want the failure to be recorded forcefully.

Comment: Make sure the assert is called (directly or indirectly) from a method with the `[TestMethod]` attribute. Make sure that that test method is being called by the proper Coded UI execution engine, eg by running the test from Visual Studio.

Comment: Is there a way to assert from a different call which is called by a test method? in other words will assert work from a not [TestMethod]?

Answer (score 0):

I found answer from this [MSDN post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f7e89111-5cdc-440d-84c8-960c34034b85/how-to-make-a-coded-ui-test-be-set-to-failed-when-an-exception-is-caught-using-trycatch-blocks?forum=vsautotest)

This error is happening because of the exception options. Need to add an exception for the assert namespace and disable both user handled and Thrown in Debug-->Exceptions

Comment: Link only answers are likely to be deleted. Please include at least an outline the details of the answer here.